# Beautiful soup fining elements of a table that are of different sizes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a page that has Auction details I like to extract. The data from these tables changes in size because there are times that not all data points are available. Is there a way to create missing columns even if they are missing in order to keep the table consistent.

This is an example of a table that has some data points missing

```
<div class="AUCTION_DETAILS">
    <table class="ad_tab" tabindex="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Auction Type:</th>
                <td class="AD_DTA">FORECLOSURE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="AD_LBL" scope="row" aria-label="Case Number">Case #:</th>
                <td class="AD_DTA"><a
                        href="/index.cfm?zaction=auction&amp;zmethod=details&amp;AID=1173868&amp;bypassPage=1">2009-020878-CA-01</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Final Judgment Amount:</th>
                <td class="AD_DTA">$183,284.23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Parcel ID:</th>
                <td class="AD_DTA"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Plaintiff Max Bid:</th>
                <td class="AD_DTA ASTAT_MSGPB">Hidden</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is an example of a table that has all the data points

```
<div class="AUCTION_DETAILS">
    <table class="ad_tab" tabindex="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Auction Type:</th>
                <td class="AD_DTA">FORECLOSURE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="AD_LBL" scope="row" aria-label="Case Number">Case #:</th>
                <td class="AD_DTA"><a
                        href="/index.cfm?zaction=auction&amp;zmethod=details&amp;AID=1312124&amp;bypassPage=1">2013-037297-CA-01</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Final Judgment Amount:</th>
                <td class="AD_DTA">$242,181.24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Parcel ID:</th>
                <td class="AD_DTA">04-3106-030-0070</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Property Address:</th>
                <td class="AD_DTA">131 W 41 ST</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="AD_LBL" scope="row"></th>
                <td class="AD_DTA">HIALEAH, FL- 33012</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Assessed Value:</th>
                <td class="AD_DTA">$201,701.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Plaintiff Max Bid:</th>
                <td class="AD_DTA ASTAT_MSGPB">Hidden</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The short table is missing all the fields below in this example. But that may vary
PropertyAddress, PropertyAddress1, AssessedValue, PlaintiffMaxBid

How would I extract existing columns and create NaN columns for the missing columns so table size is consistent.

Below are 2 samples one that has all data points and an other that has missing data points

[No_Data_Missing](https://projectcodesamples.s3.amazonaws.com/CompleteFile.html)

[Missing Data Points](https://projectcodesamples.s3.amazonaws.com/shortFile.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT

`BeautifulSoup` - Scrape your tables, store results in a `list` of `dicts` and create a `dataframe` - `pandas` will fill values from non existing keys with `NaN` - See also full example.

```
for table in soup.select('table.ad_tab'):
    data.append(dict([(row.th.text,row.td.text) for row in table.select('tr') ]))
```

`Pandas` - Iterate `list` of urls, [`pd.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) your tables, [`pd.tranpose()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) and finally [`concate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them:

```
import pandas as pd
urls = ['https://projectcodesamples.s3.amazonaws.com/CompleteFile.html','https://projectcodesamples.s3.amazonaws.com/shortFile.html']
pd.concat([df.set_index(0).T for url in urls for df in pd.read_html(url, attrs={'class':'ad_tab'})],ignore_index=True)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

urls = ['https://projectcodesamples.s3.amazonaws.com/CompleteFile.html','https://projectcodesamples.s3.amazonaws.com/shortFile.html']

data = []

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    for table in soup.select('table.ad_tab'):
            data.append(dict([(row.th.text,row.td.text) for row in table.select('tr') ]))


pd.DataFrame(data)
```

|  | Auction Type: | Case #: | Final Judgment Amount: | Parcel ID: | Plaintiff Max Bid: | Property Address: |  | Assessed Value: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | FORECLOSURE | 2009-020878-CA-01 | $183,284.23 |  | Hidden | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | FORECLOSURE | 2013-037297-CA-01 | $242,181.24 | 04-3106-030-0070 | Hidden | 131 W 41 ST | HIALEAH, FL- 33012 | $201,701.00 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 38 | FORECLOSURE | 2015-011730-CA-01 | $558,875.05 |  | nan | nan | nan | Hidden |
| 39 | FORECLOSURE | 2015-012472-CA-01 | $595,150.12 |  | nan | nan | nan | Hidden |

---

It is also possible to `append()` a new `dict` as row to your existing `dataframe`:

```
df.append({'Auction Type:': 'some value',
  'Case #:': 'some value',
  'Final Judgment Amount:': 'some value',
  'Parcel ID:': 'some value',
  'Plaintiff Max Bid:': ''}, ignore_index=True)
```

|  | Auction Type: | Case #: | Final Judgment Amount: | Parcel ID: | Plaintiff Max Bid: | Property Address: |  | Assessed Value: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | FORECLOSURE | 2009-020878-CA-01 | $183,284.23 |  | Hidden | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | FORECLOSURE | 2013-037297-CA-01 | $242,181.24 | 04-3106-030-0070 | Hidden | 131 W 41 ST | HIALEAH, FL- 33012 | $201,701.00 |
| 2 | some value | some value | some value | some value |  | nan | nan | nan |

Comment: HedgeHog your append dict code looks promising but errors "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

Comment: @LeoTorres : This can certainly be fixed, but it would be good to know what you are dealing with, it is difficult without a source that has deviations. could you please add this info to clarify the circumstances.

Comment: HedgeHog There are links now in question to provide sample data for both scenarios. Ideally I should be able to extract from both without the dataframe size changing

Comment: @LeoTorres : Thanks, updated example based on your links. Fix was that simple by selecting with `soup.select('table.ad_tab')` tables more specific.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `pandas` for this. It uses `BeautifulSoup` under the hood and is able to [read html tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) as pandas DataFrames, which you can easily export to various file formats. If you concatenate the two dataframes, pandas will fill the missing values with nan:

```
import pandas as pd

html1 = '<div class="AUCTION_DETAILS"><table class="ad_tab" tabindex="0"><tbody><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Auction Type:</th><td class="AD_DTA">FORECLOSURE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row" aria-label="Case Number">Case #:</th><td class="AD_DTA"><a href="/index.cfm?zaction=auction&amp;zmethod=details&amp;AID=1173868&amp;bypassPage=1">2009-020878-CA-01</a></td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Final Judgment Amount:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$183,284.23</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Parcel ID:</th><td class="AD_DTA"></td></tr> <tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Plaintiff Max Bid:</th><td class="AD_DTA ASTAT_MSGPB">Hidden</td></tr></tbody></table></div>'
html2 = ' <div class="AUCTION_DETAILS"><table class="ad_tab" tabindex="0"><tbody><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Auction Type:</th><td class="AD_DTA">FORECLOSURE</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row" aria-label="Case Number">Case #:</th><td class="AD_DTA"><a href="/index.cfm?zaction=auction&amp;zmethod=details&amp;AID=1312124&amp;bypassPage=1">2013-037297-CA-01</a></td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Final Judgment Amount:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$242,181.24</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Parcel ID:</th><td class="AD_DTA">04-3106-030-0070</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Property Address:</th><td class="AD_DTA">131 W 41 ST</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row"></th><td class="AD_DTA">HIALEAH, FL- 33012</td></tr> <tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Assessed Value:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$201,701.00</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Plaintiff Max Bid:</th><td class="AD_DTA ASTAT_MSGPB">Hidden</td></tr></tbody></table></div>'

df1 = pd.read_html(html1)[0] #since read_html returns a list of tables on a page, select the one you need by index, in this case [0]
df2 = pd.read_html(html2)[0]

df1 = df1.T #transpose the table
df2 = df2.T

df1 = df1.rename(columns=df1.iloc[0]).drop(df1.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True) # set the first row as headers
df2 = df2.rename(columns=df2.iloc[0]).drop(df1.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)

final_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort=False) # concatenate dataframes

final_df.to_csv('final.csv') # export to csv
```

Now, final_df will output:

|  | Auction Type: | Case #: | Final Judgment Amount: | Parcel ID: | Plaintiff Max Bid: | Property Address: | nan | Assessed Value: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | FORECLOSURE | 2009-020878-CA-01 | $183,284.23 | nan | Hidden | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | FORECLOSURE | 2013-037297-CA-01 | $242,181.24 | 04-3106-030-0070 | Hidden | 131 W 41 ST | HIALEAH, FL- 33012 | $201,701.00 |

If all tables are on the same page, you can process the page in one go with list comprehension:

```
dfs = pd.read_html(html1+html2)

dfs = [i.T for i in dfs]
dfs = [i.rename(columns=i.iloc[0]).drop(i.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True) for i in dfs]
final_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

Comment: This works here but your thinking there are only 2 tables there are 10 tables per page and I have 24151 pages. These has to be a way to adjust dataframe based on whats available in the html.

Comment: @LeoTorres The last part of my answer shows how you can load multiple tables from a single page. You might have to add some filtering to remove redundant tables from the list, but once you've got all tables from all pages you can concatenate them all in one go.

Comment: ok it took me a while to understand what you did. But the final_df fails error "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" I tried to filter dfs list using if 'FORECLOSURE' in dfs[i] but it returns false.

Comment: @LeoTorres I can debug if you share the url